# CSS background invalid property

Tags: html, css, properties, background, background-color

I am trying to set the background color of the `<header>` tag. However this is giving me an error `Invalid Property` within my inspection window.

My code(below) is completely fine.

```
header {
  background: #009640;
  background: #009640;
  padding: 7px 10%;
}
```

The first `background` gives an `Invalid Property`. The second line works perfectly fine.

I've tried commenting and uncommenting both lines, the first line keeps giving me 'Invalid Property'.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i copied the first one from a chat client. The second line is written by hand.

Comment: Which tool/validator is giving you this message? Why have two `background` definitions?

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that the first property is 'Invalid' and the second one is correct. (this has nothing to do with overriding the previous line). The validator is the Firefox Inspection Window.

Comment: If you copy & pasted it, perhaps there are some invisible characters tripping up the parser. What happens if you re-type the line (or just have one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-color` when you just set the color (one time).

Comment: `background` should be valid with only the colour, though: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background

Comment: Yes, it should, but there are more 'Invalid Property' errors reported on just using it for background-color (perhaps when dealing with inherited values for background).